# Encapsulation of ObservableCollection does not work

Tags: c#, .net, properties, observablecollection, encapsulation

My property is:

```
private static ObservableCollection<Wynik> lottoWyniki = new ObservableCollection<Wynik>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Wynik> LottoWyniki
    {
        get { return lottoWyniki; }
        set { lottoWyniki = value; }
    }
```

And when later in the code I want to add objects to this collection:

```
for(i=2;i<=7;i++)
                LottoWyniki.Add(new Wynik(i,Date));
```

Every new obcject that I'm adding is replacing all objects that were there before. So at the finish of this code I've got ObservableCollection that contains one (last) object repeated 6 times. What I'm I doing wrong?

EDIT:
In constructor of Wynik I'm doing:

```
public Wynik (int l, DateTime d) 
{  
    Liczba = l;  
    Data = d; 
}
```

Class Wynik:

```
class Wynik
{
    private static DateTime data;
    public static DateTime Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    private static int liczba;
    public static int Liczba
    {
        get { return liczba; }
        set { liczba = value; }
    }

    public Wynik (int l, DateTime d)
    {
        Liczba = l;
        Data = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted wouldn't cause that behaviour so I suspect your actual code involes your loop variable being captured.

Comment: When I debugging program I can see that single increment of a loop is increasing my variable ones at time (i++) and properly adding it to collection. But it is adding object on every index instead of one (next) index.

Comment: @r9s When you are debugging, if you put a breakpoint on your add, what is the value of i and are you doing anything interesting in the constructor of Wynik?

Comment: @DavidL At start value of the i is 2 and increasing. In constructor of Wynik I'm doing: http://pastebin.com/hf3c5J51 (I don't know is this interesting :P).

Comment: @r9s I added your code snippet to your question for readability :).  It seems this should be working.  How are you accessing the collection to see the results?

Comment: @DavidL I'm debugging LottoWyniki after loop finished.

Comment: @r9s Just for giggles, try making a new list of all of the objects and then adding them to the collection.  Something else must be occurring

Comment: @DavidL I did make a collection of <int> and it worked perfectly, so I think it's something with Wynik..

Comment: I added full code of Wynik.

Comment: Why are the properties of `Wynik` static? That means every instance of `Wynik` will share the same `Data` and `Liczba` properties which surely isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your class's variables are static.  Try changing all properties to non-static members and this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I read this answer and was about to comment along the lines of both "this should be a comment" and "there's no way he'd do that".  Then I saw the edit to the OP in which this clearly is the problem.  (Please change this so that it's not in the form of a question though, clarifying questions belong in comments, not answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to this:

```
class Wynik
{
    private DateTime data;
    public DateTime Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    private int liczba;
    public int Liczba
    {
        get { return liczba; }
        set { liczba = value; }
    }

    public Wynik (int l, DateTime d)
    {
        Liczba = l;
        Data = d;
    }
}
```

You problem is that your properties were all `static`, that means that every instance of your class shares the *same* property. It wasn't that you had an array with the same object 6 times, you had 6 distinct objects, you just had no way of telling them apart because they all had the same value for `Data` and `Liczba`.

Comment: Rather than just providing a code dump, consider explaining what you changed and why it fixes the problem.

Comment: @MattBurland I'm helping you improve the quality of your posts.  By pointing out problems in posts they can be fixed, rather than ignoring them and letting the low quality content remain on the site.  You should be willing to accept constructive criticism of the content that you post publicly, particularly on SO where such feedback is highly encouraged.

Comment: @MattBurland You should be prepared for what you post to be judged based on what's there, not based on what you'll add at some time in the future.  If you aren't prepared to have your content judged as is, then don't post it.  If you post it anyway, you should be prepared to accept the feedback of what you posted.